# Datepicker Fechas - No se abre Calendario

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando una web de reservas online, y deseo poner en un div el número de noches que el huésped se alojará en mi hotel.

Mi duda es la siguiente: Si selecciono una fecha de entrada (check_in), que automáticamente en fecha de salida check_out), se me **bloqueen TODAS las fechas anteriores** debido a que debe ser una fecha superior. **¿Por qué no me sale el Datepicker?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculoNoches.js"></script>
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#check_in").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateStr) {
                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                if (minDate) { 
                    m.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
                } 
                $('#check_out').datepicker('setDate', minDate).
                datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            }
            });

            $('#check_out').datepicker().on("input click", function(e) {
                console.log("Fecha salida cambiada: ", e.target.value);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">

            <label for="check_in">Entrada:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

            <label for="check_out">Salida:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" id="check_out" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

No me muestra ningún error pulsando F12 en consola.

Comment: Aquí el problema no es el método, el cual funciona perfectamente, sino que al parecer hay un problema de comprensión sobre el modo en que funcionan las cosas. Me parece que dos escenarios son posibles: **A:**¿Las fechas de entrada y salida las recoges en el formulario?, o **B:**¿O se las pides a un registro de la base de datos?. Si es **A** no necesitas PHP para hacer el cálculo. Si es **B** tienes que enviar una petición al servidor a través de Ajax, sacar los datos, hacer el cálculo y actualizar el div : `<div class="calcular_dias"></div>` con la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: La cuestión es A. Las fechas se recogen de los campos rellenados en el formulario. ¿Tendré que tener una funcion donde se recojan las dos fechas y restarlas, no?

Comment: Bien, si estás manejando una base de datos de reservaciones, **(A)** sería lógico únicamente en el caso de que estés ingresando un nuevo cliente. En ese caso, si necesitas el cálculo de noches para algo, puedes hacerlo sin tener que enviar nada al servidor, basándote en el valor de los inputs. En cambio, si vas a trabajar con clientes existentes, lo que deberías hacer es tener un `select` con los clientes... o un buscador de clientes, pedir a la base de datos las fechas de entrada y salida, hacer el cálculo y actualizar el `div`. Intuyo que hay un problema de enfoque.

Comment: Solo es a nivel informativo. Deseo que únicamente con el valor que tomen los campos rellenar esa información para el cliente. En ningún caso se referirá a la base de datos. Para la base de datos tengo información en columnas "check_in" y "check_out". El número de noches es a nivel informativo.

Comment: Entonces puedes hacerlo con una función de JavaScript o de jQuery, no es necesario recurrir a PHP para eso.

Comment: El problema es que el código simplicado del "date_diff" en un archivo de pruebas: pruebas.php, sí me funciona pero al llevarlo al input check_in, check_out me da error.

Comment: Solucionado con Javascript pero con una duda que quiero que sea un pequeño retoque. Pregunta editada.

Comment: El problema original planteado en esta pregunta era sobre **restar fechas**. Luego surgió otra duda y la pregunta fue modificada **sustancialmente**. Hacer eso no es acorde con el formato del sitio por varios motivos, entre ellos, porque quita el sentido a las respuestas ya proporcionadas (dos respuestas en este caso que intentan resolver el problema original planteado). Cuando se modifica sustancialmente la pregunta el esfuerzo por responder ya hecho es ignorado. Considero que esta pregunta debe ser restablecida a su estado original, de lo contrario, las respuestas dadas quedan desfasadas.

Answer (score 2):

Acomodala a como te convenga.
Mira si esta function te funciona:

```
function compararFecha($fecha){
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$datetime1 = new DateTime("now");//fecha actual 
$datetime2 = new DateTime($fecha); 
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$dias= $interval->format('%R%a');
return $dias;
}
```

Para realizar lo de mostrar de una vez el div supongo que debes usar un onchange. Saludos.

Comment: Llamando a esta función en el input fecha_final en un evento "onChange" supongo que funcionaría... probaré. Acepto más sugerencias.

Comment: Esta bien cualquier duda comenta y respondere

Comment: Ya la tengo. Edito pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Según lo dicho en comentarios, si no vas a consultar nada en el servidor, puedes seleccionar las fechas en cada input y hacer los cálculos directamente. Luego en el div imprimes el resultado del cálculo, como podrás probar en el code snippet de más abajo.

Las llamadas al servidor deben hacerse para hacer operaciones que obligatoriamente tengan que pasar por el servidor. Ten en cuenta que cada llamada al servidor tiene un coste de rendimiento y de consumo de recursos de red en el cliente y el servidor.

Aquí he usado una herramienta de jQuery UI llamada [DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), la cual, cuando haces click en tus dos inputs te abre un hermoso calendario para escoger tu fecha. La mejora no es sólo a nivel de experiencia del usuario, sino también de exactitud, ya que desde la fecha seleccionada puedes construir un objeto fecha con el cual calcularás la diferencia en días y podrás hacer cualquier otra operación que requiera exactitud. No sería lo mismo que tener que escribir la fecha a mano, tomando en cuenta que de ese modo el margen de error sería mucho mayor.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#btnReservar").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fechaEntrada = $('#txtEntrada').datepicker("getDate");
    var fechaSalida = $('#txtSalida').datepicker("getDate");

    var totalDias = Math.abs(Math.ceil((fechaEntrada - fechaSalida) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));

    var strMensaje = "*** Total de días entre " +
      fechaEntrada.toLocaleDateString() + " y " + fechaSalida.toLocaleDateString() + ": " + totalDias;
    console.log(strMensaje);

    $('.calcular_dias').html(strMensaje);

  });


  /*Establecemos el minDate del segundo DP*/

  $("#txtEntrada").datepicker({

    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
      var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      if (minDate) { 
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
      } 
        $('#txtSalida').datepicker('setDate', minDate).
        datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
    }
  });

/*Listener del 2do DP  por si lo necesitas para algo*/
  $('#txtSalida').datepicker()
    .on("input click", function(e) {
      console.log("Fecha salida cambiada: ", e.target.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mireserva" id="mireserva" method="POST" class="form">
  <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
  <label for="check_in">Entrada:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtEntrada" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" readonly="readonly">
  <label for="check_out">Salida:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtSalida" placeholder="Fecha de salida">

  <div class="calcular_dias">

  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="btnReservar">Reservar</button><br/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Eso ya lo tengo entendido pero ahora viene el problema que permite integrar una fecha de salida inferior a la fecha de entrada. Y eso no debería permitirse, deberían ser ocultas las fechas anteriores a la fecha de entrada establecida.

Comment: @omaza1990 he editado el código otorgándole la posibilidad de establecer la fecha mínima del segundo DP a un día después de la fecha del primer DP. Espero te sirva.

Comment: He comprobado que funciona correctamente pero voy a echarle un ojo, aún no vi el código cualquier duda que tengo le comentaré.

Comment: @omaza1990 de acuerdo. Considero que deberías cambiar el título de la pregunta y también agregar las etiqueta javascript y jquery ya que al final la pregunta estaba más orientada a código del lado del cliente que del lado del servidor (PHP), por los motivos explicados en los comentarios.

Comment: Al llevarlo a mi código me da el siguiente error en la línea 1: datepicker.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at datepicker.js:1

Comment: @omaza1990 parece que no estás incluyendo la biblioteca de jQuery. El código necesita esa biblioteca para correr. Es lo primero que se ve en la segunda parte del code snippet: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Esa y las demás bibliotecas deben ir en la sección `<head>`  del HTML. Si ya lo tienes es muy probable que hayas omitido algún signo, alguna llave o paréntesis de más o de menos.

Comment: Tengo todas las librerías y los paréntesis o corchetes o comillas todo está correcto.

Comment: @omaza1990 Conviene que muestres el código como lo tienes para revisarlo. Si funciona en el snippet te debería funcionar. Algún error debe haber en alguna parte.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68768/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Edité mi pregunta modificada y con el código simplicado pero no funciona en mi programa.

Comment: @omaza1990 lo correcto habría sido **plantear una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema**. Así está concebido el formato del sitio. Las preguntas respondidas a dudas concretas no sirven solamente para ti, sino también para futuros usuarios. Pero si cada vez que te surge una duda replanteas la pregunta, la editas, retiras el check de solucionado, etc, da la impresión de que quienes respondemos somos una especie de *servicio al cliente* que tenemos que estar también editando nuestras respuestas... Este sitio no es un foro, está dedicado a la resolución de **un problema** en concreto. Saludos.